# How to fetch primary key id for duplicate field values in PHP MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table consisting two column, id(primary key) and name.

I also have a search box to search them. Say I type in some name 'John Smith' and click search.Now I can get the name and other details using the code below but my question is say, there there are two users with the same name John Smith, how do I fetch the id of only the user that has been typed in and not some other because obviously I can't use where condition like name='$name'. That would be ambiguous. Any suggestions would be of great help since I am not able to figure out how to achieve this.

Here is my code. I know that I shouldn't be using mysql_* functions, I will implement that later. For now I just need to figure this thing out.

**index.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include('db.php');

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'search'){
    $name = $_POST['typeahead'];
    header('location:result.php');
  }
 ?>

</script>   
</head>
<body>

<div class="row" style="position: relative; top:10px; left: 250px;">

<form name='test' action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" style="width: 200px;" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Type a name">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="search"></input>
</form>

</div>   

</body>
</html>
```

**result.php**

```
<?php
 //echo the name that is typed in the search box.
?>
```

Comment: How can you tell the difference between `John Smith` and `John Smith` when all you search on is... `John Smith`? The best thing to do is have an intermediary step that displays both `John Smith`s and asks the user to pick which one they mean. Perhaps display extra data such as address or phone number...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, how do code differentiate between the 2 users with the same name when you are not able to do it.
 Therefore, append some extra information with the names so that user is able to pick the required one.